# Allegory: 'a grain of sugar in your eyes'

Tags: meaning-in-context

[Source:](http://grantland.com/hollywood-prospectus/crime-and-punishment-the-americans-soars-in-its-brutal-third-season/) ‘by Andy Greenwald BA (Brown University), 2015 Mar 26

> But to watch The Americans is to be forced to sink deeper and deeper into uncomfortable truths. To borrow a phrase from Betty, the doomed widow in the machine repair shop, it’s impossible to watch this show with even **a grain of sugar in your eyes**.

1. Am I right that this is an [allegory](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/23590)? If not, what [trope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figure_of_speech#Categories_of_figures_of_speech) is this?

2. I ask about the figurative meaning, and NOT about the literal meaning. I guess that **sugar**  means a Polyannish or [saccharine](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/saccharine?q=saccharine+) or sugary mentality, but why mention the eyes? This mention seems contradictory, because any foreign physical object that contacts the eye, hurts. How

Comment: Note to self: The author studied English: http://soundsgoodjj.blogspot.com/2005/11/interview-w-andy-greenwald.html

Comment: I take this rather literally: the show tastes so bad that even with a grain of sugar in your eyes, it still tastes so bad that it's impossible to watch the show.

Comment: Maybe Mr Greenwald is a synaesthete.

Comment: No, Greenwald is paraphrasing a line from the show.

Comment: When they translated it to Swedish it said hallucination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 It is a metaphor. This is how Betty spins the phrase in S03E09 of the show.

2 One mentions the eyes because one watches the TV show using one's sense of vision. Metaphorical sugar in one's eyes does not hurt. [This blog post of mine](http://karamazov.livejournal.com/13824.html) goes into more detail.

Comment: Does S03 suggest that you're expecting the number of seasons to go into the double digits?

Comment: @TRomano It's a [standard system](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en-US&ie=UTF-8&source=android-browser&q=s03e09&gws_rd=ssl#q=s03e09&hl=en-US&start=10). Seasons rarely top 9, but episodes often do; the double digits for both keep things looking nice. As for this show, non mi piace.

Answer (score 3):

(Native American English speaker here.)

I've never heard of "a grain of sugar in your eyes", and I don't get it. Google only turns up two pages for the phrase: your source, and this page.

Here are two guesses:

(1) Maybe the author was trying to invent a clever new figure of speech, and it misfired. This might be the sort of thing that inspired the proverb "[kill your darlings](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Arthur_Quiller-Couch)".

(2) Maybe it's a reference to something that happened on the television program that the article is about.

The quotation suggests that hypothesis #2 is correct: it's probably something Betty said. Maybe Betty tried speaking figuratively and flopped.

Comment: A cliche, intentionally mangled.  A bit of wreckage on the Mixed Metaphor Highway.

Answer (score -2):

It means that no amount of sweetness or "sugar-coating" is going to blind you to the faults. Also, it's not an allegory, but an idiom.

Comment: That's one possible interpretation, but it would be nice if you supported your theory somehow (for example, with links to other uses of this expression).